# Unable to connect ArcPy with ArcMap to MS SQL Server accessed via ArcSDE

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, connection

Why can I not connect my ArcPy to our enterprise database hosted on a Microsoft SQL Server?

I'm running Python 2.7, ArcMap 10.6.1, MSSQL Server 12.0 (2014)

I've created an SDE connection file in ArcCatalog and can browse the database in Catalog, so I know it works but as soon as I try using that file in Python it returns nothing.

This is my bare bones Python script below

```
print ('Initialising arcpy')
import arcpy

DATABASE = 'C:\\Users\\T6358590\\Desktop\\Newfolder\\library\\2-sde-Networks.sde'
print(DATABASE)

arcpy.env.workspace = DATABASE

fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
print(fcList)
```

::Output::

```
========= RESTART: C:\Users\T6358590\Desktop\NewFolder\arcpy_list.py =========
Initialising arcpy
C:\Users\T6358590\Desktop\Newfolder\library\2-sde-Networks.sde
[]
```

Comment: Best practice in Python is to follow [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) conventions, which recommends lower-case variable names. Was the connection file assembled on a different host? Does that connection file work on any other hosts? What does `arcpy.Describe` report on the `dataType` of the object?

Comment: @Vince I've now tried it on 5 computers, i could get it to run on 3 of them.. 2 failed.. those 3 that worked I have admin privilages the other 2 I don't. I didn't think this needed admin prvilages to run?

Comment: Geodatabase connections certainly don't require admin, but you're only providing a piece of the problem, so it's impossible to know how the server has been configured.

Comment: what additional information do you require?

Comment: Well, the body of the question should mention there are multiple computers involved, and admin rights, and how the connection is configured, and which machines are part of the domain and some basic info on the nature of the failure. This looking like a Windows configuration issue than a GIS one, but you should also be talking to Esri Tech Support.